# I want to remove blank values from nested ActionController::Parameters hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have ActionController::Parameters hash and I want to remove the blank value from manager_id key which is array

Hash

```
params = {
  "user" => {
    "name" => "xxxxxx",
    "reporting_emails" => "xxxx@xxxx.com",
    "password" => "[FILTERED]",
    "email" => "xxxxx@xxx.com",
    "crm_user_id" => "2",
    "role" => "telecaller",
    "archived" => "0",
    "can_export" => "0",
    "user_managers_attributes" => {
      "0" => {
        "manager_id" => ["", "48"]
      }
    }
  },
  "commit" => "Save"
}
```

Comment: Do you just want the empty string removed from array or find out why it's there in the first place and correct?

Comment: I just want to remove empty string from array

Answer (score 0):

To remove the empty string from `"manager_id"` array. This should work using the Array `reject` method.

```rb
params = {"user"=>{"name"=>"xxxxxx", "reporting_emails"=>"xxxx@xxxx.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"xxxxx@xxx.com", "crm_user_id"=>"2", "role"=>"telecaller", "archived"=>"0", "can_export"=>"0", "user_managers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"manager_id"=>["", "48"]}}}, "commit"=>"Save"}

array = params["user"]["user_managers_attributes"]["0"]["manager_id"]

# remove any blank values
array.reject(&:empty?)
```

Comment: I am getting TypeError - no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer: for values 0

Comment: That occurs when an invalid type for a key is used in a Hash. Can you provide a small code snippet of where it's failling?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `user_managers_attributes` may contain multiple entries in which case `transform_values` will catch all of them

```rb
params['user']['user_managers_attributes'].transform_values { |v| v['manager_id'].reject!(&:blank?) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Input

```
hash={"user"=>{"name"=>"xxxxxx", "reporting_emails"=>"xxxx@xxxx.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"xxxxx@xxx.com", "crm_user_id"=>"2", "role"=>"telecaller", "archived"=>"0", "can_export"=>"0", "user_managers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"manager_id"=>["", "48"]}}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```

Code

```
hash['user']['user_managers_attributes'].each do |k,v|
  v['manager_id'].reject!(&:empty?)
end

p hash
```

Output

```
{"user"=>{"name"=>"xxxxxx", "reporting_emails"=>"xxxx@xxxx.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"xxxxx@xxx.com", "crm_user_id"=>"2", "role"=>"telecaller", "archived"=>"0", "can_export"=>"0", "user_managers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"manager_id"=>["48"]}}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```